# Overloading operator outside template struct

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have the following code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template <class F>
struct CMPLX {

    F Re, Im;

    struct _printnice {
        F Re, Im;
        string sep;
        _printnice(const F& Re, const F& Im, const string& sep) : Re(Re), Im(Im), sep(sep) {}
    };

    CMPLX <F> (F Re, F Im) : Re(Re), Im(Im) {}

    _printnice PrintNice(const string& sep="\t"){
        return _printnice(Re, Im, sep);
    }

};

template<class F>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const CMPLX<F> c){
    cout << c.Re << " + " << c.Im << "i";
}

template<class F>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const CMPLX<F> :: _printnice p){
    cout << p.Re << p.sep << p.Im;
}

int main(){
    CMPLX<float> c(2.0,1.0);
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << c.PrintNice() << endl;

}
```

I introduce a sub-struct `_printnice` in order to overload the operator `<<` and have differently-formatted output of my `CMPLX` class. However, this throws an error
**expected unqualified-id before ‘p’** and I don't know how to solve this (my knowledge on templates is very limited).

I try to change the 2nd definition of `<<` to the following which works, but I have to specify the type, which is frowned-upon:

```c
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const CMPLX <float> :: _printnice p){
    cout << p.Re << p.sep << p.Im;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues with your approach. The first is that `_printnice` is a dependent name and as such you need to add an extra `typename`. If that were fixed you would end up with:

```
template<class F>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, typename CMPLX<F>::_printnice const & p)
```

The problem with this code, as Dietmar pointed out in a previous answer, is that `F` is in a non deducible context, and this will fail.

One simple solution is to define the operator inside the scope of the `_printnice` code, where the `typename`:

```
template <class F>
struct CMPLX {
   //...
   struct _printnice {
      friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, _printnice const & p ) {
         // print here
         return o;
      }
   }
   //...
};
```

Inside the definition of `_printnice`, the type is known to be a type and thus the `typename` is no longer required. The overloaded `operator<<` will be found by Argument Dependent Lookup, and because it refers to this particular instantiation of the type, there is no template arguments to deduce.

Comment: Yes this way its deducible as no longer nested-name-specifier specified using a qualified-id, this is great. The only thing is OP asked this to be 'outside template struct'...

Comment: @Gob00st I don't think I asked for it to be outside, if you got this impression, that I apologize. And thanks David, this works! I didn't know you can fully define a `friend` function, I always used it only to declare it inside and define outside.

Comment: @Gob00st: In the modified case, there are no template arguments to deduce (i.e. it cannot be deducible since there are no deducible arguments). The compiler will generate a non-templated `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,CMPLX<X>::_printnice const&)` for each type `X` for which the `_printnice` nested type is used. I cannot find where the OP asks for 'outside template struct'... at any rate outside of the template struct it is not possible.

Comment: @both: sorry I think I am mistaken here.+1

Answer (score 1):

In the function:

```
template <typename F>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, CMPLX<F>::_printnice p);
```

`F` is not not in a deducible context.  (See §14.8.2.5.)

Comment: From c++ 11 standard :: The nested-name-specifier of a type that was specified using a qualified-id.

Answer (score 0):

NB. This is not a answer. David answered it already. FWIW, just fixed a few things so it can compile & runable under gcc 4.72.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template <class F>
struct CMPLX {

    F Re, Im;

    struct _printnice {

        F Re, Im;
        string sep;
        _printnice(const F& Re, const F& Im, const string& sep) : Re(Re), Im(Im), sep(sep) {}

        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const _printnice& p){
            cout << p.Re << p.sep << p.Im;
            return os;
        }
    };

    CMPLX <F> (F Re, F Im) : Re(Re), Im(Im) {}

    _printnice PrintNice(const string& sep="\t"){
        return _printnice(Re, Im, sep);
    }

};

template<class F>
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const CMPLX<F> c){
    cout << c.Re << " + " << c.Im << "i";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    CMPLX<float> c(2.0,1.0);
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << c.PrintNice() << endl;
}

//result
/*
2 + 1i
2       1
*/
```

Comment: The original code after using the other answer runs perfectly in `gcc 4.4.5`, so what's the point?

Comment: @tohec:How come it's perfect? No return values for two operator<<()  for starters...